# How to read only integers from file?

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner

I got a problem when I'm trying to read int from text file.
I'm using this kind of code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

 File  fileName =new File( "D:\\input.txt");
 try {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(fileName);
     c = in.nextInt();
     n = in.nextInt();

 } catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("File not Found!!!");
 }
```

If my text is edit like this

```
30
40
```

So it will work (meaning c=30, n=40).
But if I want to edit the text file that will be like this

```
c=30
n=40
```

My code will not work.

How can  I change my code to read only the numbers and ignore the "c=" and n="
or any others chars besides the numbers?

Comment: Does `c=30` look like an integer to you? Is it greater than `0723`? What about `0xA0F2`?

Comment: @Raffaele, you better read again

Comment: @Alexander you better read my comment again. `c=30` is not an integer parsable by [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It's called *sarcasm*

Comment: Leaving you sarcasm aside. I don't think OP has decided a file format yet nor will mark an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your lines using `Scanner.nextLine`, split each line on `=`, and then convert the 2nd part to integer.

Remember to do the check - `Scanner.hasNextLine` before you read any line. So, you need to use a `while` loop to read each line.

A Simple implementation, you can extend it according to your need: -

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] tokens = line.split("=");

    try {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now if you want to use those numbers later on, you can also add them in an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the format you want to use in the input file then it would be better if you make use of [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). You won't need to care about the parsing.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\input.txt")));
c = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("c"));
n = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("n"));
```

You can read more about the [simple line-oriented format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).

Answer (score 0):

you could read line by line(`Scanner.nextLine`) and check every character in the line by asking `isDigit()`

Answer (score 0):

If your data line will always be in the same format `x=12345`, use a regex to get the numeric value from the line